# Magento Custom Payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I Created a Custom Payment Method Module and its work perfectly but in the redirect to success page i use this code below:
`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure' => true, '_query'=> $parameters));`

in this code i created an array named `_query` with all parameters from external gateway `$parameters` so my question **how i can read there `parameters` in success page** in checkout `success.phtml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access request variables by using these methods:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams('_query'); // Gets everything, $_GET and $_POST
```

Not

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('_query');
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you should be able to retrieve this array of parameters by doing:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('_query');
```

Comment: i use your code but the response is null (nothing retrieved) any help plz ?

Comment: @mahmoudismail what does `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()` give you ?

Comment: In Success Page my code is `<div class="page-title">
 <?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('_query'); ?>
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Your order has been received..') ?></h1>
</div>` but print an empty array

Comment: @mahmoudismail try to see what you're getting when you use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams()` ?

Comment: i get an empty array  `array(0) { }`

Comment: @mahmoudismail what if you change `_query` to `query` in both your redirect and your template ?